# How to develop a message bot which can answer for asked questions using java

Tags: java, bots, stanford-nlp

I want to create a bot which can answer for user when he type q question on it. The answers should be given using analysis on data available on database. Forecasting features also should be addressed.

I am planning to use Java as programming language and CoreNLP libraries for implementation.

I am thankful if anyone could tell which steps I should follow when developing the application and what technologies should I use to get decisions in this app?

Comment: First you need to learn about NLP (natural language processing). Then you could able to get an idea based on your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After identifying the message how I get the answer for it? What technologies can I use to get the decision?